# check all inputs value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, frontend

Suppose inputs are getting generated dynamically as listed below

```
<input type="text" name="room[0][0]">
<input type="text" name="room[0][1]">
<input type="text" name="room[0][2]">
<input type="text" name="room[0][3]">


<input type="text" name="room[1][0]">
<input type="text" name="room[1][1]">
<input type="text" name="room[1][2]">
<input type="text" name="room[1][3]">
```

On submit, I want to check that all inputs have value using `jQuery`, otherwise it should be focused to that input and it should show `required` Message.

***NOTE: There can be hundreds of input types and don't want to give class to prevent dom element size***

Comment: Why don't you just add the `required` attribute to all of them?

Comment: these inputs are getting generated dynamically through jquery

Comment: And why can't jQuery give them the `required` attribute when it does that?

Comment: In some devices, ```required``` is not working

Comment: See the linked question for how to find all the inputs with no value. If the result is not empty, display the required message and focus on the first one.

Comment: Or use a validation plugin.